# How to get my wireless card recognized in Arch Linux running on a Dell XPS 13 9310

Tags: wireless-networking, arch-linux

I just completed an Arch Linux download with Linux Kernel `5.11.11-arch-1` on m Dell XPS 13 9310, which uses an AX1650 wireless card.  During the install process, I was able to use the `ip a` command to see the and it recognized that I had a wireless device (i.e. `wlan0`) and I used the `iwctl` command to scan for a wireless signal and connect my device to the router.

However, despite the fact that the Arch installer recognized my wireless card, as soon as I completed the install and rebooted my computer, it no longer recognizes that I have a wireless card.

If I type `ip add` it only presents this one option, which I believe is bluetooth, but it is certainly not my wireless card (i.e. `wlan0`)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00. brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I can connect to the internet with a wired connect; however, until I can get Arch to recognize that I do indeed have a wireless card, I cannot connect over wireless.  Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=247705) on the official Arch Linux site?

Comment: I have seen that post.  However, in the post you mention, Arch does recognize that there is a wireless card, in my problem, Arch does not!

Comment: Good catch. Wonder if there is a BIOS setting? Seems all to be a hardware issue if that is the case.

Comment: When you installed Archlinux on your Dell you shouldn't have installed the Wireless driver. Would you manage to connect that laptop to Internet by ethernet port? That way you could try to install the Wireless drivers on that.